# The REST version of this request is not supported by this release of the Storage Emulator

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

After upgrading my version of Azure Storage Explorer, my code stop working with the following message:

> "The REST version of this request is not supported by this release of
>   the Storage Emulator. Please upgrade the storage emulator to the
>   latest version. Refer to the following URL for more information:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=392237"

My version of Azure Storage Explorer is 0.8.16.

Basically the code to upload to azure tends to be like:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");        
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = this.blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
byte[] CoverImageBytes = null; 
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream()); 
CoverImageBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)file.Length);
await blockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(CoverImageBytes, 0,(int)file.Length);
```

The exception throws at the last line.

**UPDATE**

1) What is the version of storage emulator you're running?

**V5.1**

2) In your code, what is the version of Storage Client library you're using?

**8.4.0** [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/)

Comment: I don't think this error has anything to do with Azure Storage Explorer. Can you please tell us: 1) What is the version of storage emulator you're running? 2) In your code, what is the version of Storage Client library you're using?

Comment: Forgot to mention all that info. Updated the question, thanks @GauravMantri

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because Storage Client Library 8.4 targets REST API version `2017-04-17` where as Storage Emulator Version 5.1 targets REST API version `2016-05-31`.

You can do one of the two things:

1. Install latest version of Storage Emulator (5.2 at this time).
2. Downgrade storage client library to 8.3 which supports REST API version `2016-05-31`.

My recommendation would be to  go with #1 i.e. use the latest version of Storage Emulator.